# Explain execution of condition?

Tags: c

I am learning c programming.I have been solving some question online for practice.I came across this question

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    short int i = 2;
    float f = 3;
    if (sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(float))
        printf("float\n");
    else if (sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(short int))
        printf("short int\n");
}
```

since `(x==2)` will give `0` because the condition doesn't match then the ternary operator will give `i` which is `short int`.It's size is `2` which is not the equal size of the `float`.
But this program is printing float. Can someone tell me how it is possible?

Comment: sizeof() is a compile-time operator, not runtime.

Comment: @OldProgrammer for a VLA it will be evaluated at run-time.

Comment: @Olaf (just for the sake of completeness...) and that is the __only__ expection, otherwise, _"...the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
integer constant."_

Comment: That is problematic code at best. Better us `_Generic` to determine the type of an object. But actually this is not necessary, because C is statically typed and the type is bound to the expression accessing it, not the object.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: My comment does not imply different.

Comment: @Olaf I never implied that, was just saying....

Answer (score 2):

The expression is not evaluated, just the type, and for

```
cond ? float : short int
```

"common type" would be `float`.

Comment: It's not `bool`, it's `int`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: `x == 2` is `bool` in C++ (previous tag of the question) and `int` in C (current tag). Replaced by un-typed `cond`.

Comment: Oh, I guess I missed that part, but since the tag is updated, would you mind fixing this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You missed one `sizeof` when reading.

It is not comparing 2 with `sizeof(float)`; it is comparing the `sizeof` of the expression with the `sizeof(float)`.

The program never runs the code inside `sizeof()`. The compiler checks what type it would have *if* that code ran. In that case, the ternary would return either a `float` or a `short int`. Looking at the code we know that, *if* the code ran, it would return the value of `i` because `x == 2` is false, but since the compiler never runs this code, it only sees the types of the things in the ternary expression. Since the ternary expression can be either a `float` or an `int`, the compiler goes with the wider type (just like it does when you add a float and an int). And that's why the `sizeof` as a whole returns the same size of a `float`.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'sizeof the expression'? how do we calculate sizeof expression?

Comment: Edited the answer with a longer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are seeing the following line:

```
if (sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(float))
```

Is:

```
if (sizeof(short int) == sizeof(float)) // after expression is simlpified
```

However, the `sizeof()` function is a compile-time function, not a run-time function. This means that the shortened if-else expression inside the `sizeof()` will not be evaluated before the `sizeof()` function is run, since the if-else statement is a run-time expression. Hence, your `sizeof()` function will see the following:

```
if (sizeof (int ? float : short int) == sizeof (float)) {
```

When there is anything in an if-condition that is **not** zero, that if-condition evaluates to *true* by default. Hence here, the `int` evaluates to true, so the argument passed to `sizeof()` will be `float`. Since:

```
sizeof(float) == sizeof(float)
```

Is true, ***float*** will be output as a result.

This is resulting in your first if-statement being true.

Answer (score 0):

To <del>add to</del> nitpick already existing answers, quoting from `C11`, chapter §6.5.9, *Equality operators*, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `==` (equal to) and `!=` (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational
>   operators except for their lower precedence. Each of the operators yields `1` if the
>   specified relation is true and `0` if it is false. **The result has type `int`.**

So, what you're writing is equivalent to

```
 if (sizeof( int ? float : short int) == sizeof(float))
```

which makes the result true.

Comment: if you want to quote standard, the type of ternary operation would be more appropriate.